# Как устроены append-optimized таблицы в GreenPlum(Arenadata DB)?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Из [статьи Yandex Cloud](https://cloud.yandex.ru/ru/docs/managed-greenplum/concepts/tables) : Таблицы такого типа обеспечивают строковое и колоночное хранение. Таблицы для строкового хранения сокращенно называют AO-таблицами (append-optimized), а колоночного — AOCO-таблицами (append-optimized column-oriented). Оба вида таблиц реализованы на основе вспомогательных heap-таблиц. Данные в таблицах AO и AOCO хранятся в сегментных файлах, которые состоят из блоков произвольного объема.

Из статьи [BigDataSchool](https://bigdataschool.ru/blog/greenplum-tables-and-data-types.html):  хранилище, оптимизированным для добавления (AO, append-optimized storage) таблиц и разделов, которые нечасто обновляются после начальной загрузки, а последующие вставки выполняются только в пакетных операциях. Следует избегать выполнения одноэлементных операций INSERT, UPDATE или DELETE в AO-таблицах. Допустимы конкурентные пакетные операции INSERT, но не пакетные UPDATE или DELETE. Эта модель предназначена для больших таблиц, которые загружаются один раз, редко обновляются и часто запрашиваются для аналитической обработки запросов.

Из статьи [VMware](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum/7/greenplum-database/admin_guide-ddl-ddl-storage.html#topic38) : Перемещение больших таблиц фактов в модель хранения, оптимизированную для добавления, устраняет накладные расходы на хранение информации о видимости обновлений для каждой строки, экономя около 20 байтов на строку. Это позволяет сделать структуру страницы более компактной и простой в оптимизации. Модель хранения таблиц, оптимизированных для добавления, оптимизирована для массовой загрузки данных. INSERT

---

Понятна цель создания AO-таблиц: ускорение батчёвых вставок в таблицу, возможность колоночного хранения и сжатия. Но совершенно непонятно "как" это реализовано. Только в статье Яндекса что-то вскользь упоминается про вспомогательные таблицы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё-таки реализованы AO-таблицы под капотом?